# Parsing JSON data in a good way

Tags: python, json

I have some `JSON` structured outputs that I would like to parse and get some values from it. But my attempts are not good and viable in deeper nested `JSON`. What is a good way to get keys and values from the `JSON` example below?

Let's say I want to have below data for each `ISIS` neighbor:

```
0192.0168.0001,state,hostname,ipv4Address
0192.0168.0002,state,hostname,ipv4Address
```

```json
{
  "vrfs": {
    "default": {
      "isisInstances": {
        "XXX": {
          "neighbors": {
            "0192.0168.0001": {
              "adjacencies": [
                {
                  "state": "up",
                  "circuitId": "01",
                  "routerIdV4": "0.0.0.0",
                  "interfaceName": "Port-Channel1",
                  "lastHelloTime": 1651827049,
                  "level": "level-2",
                  "snpa": "P2P",
                  "hostname": "paris",
                  "details": {
                    "stateChanged": 1651599426,
                    "grSupported": "Supported",
                    "interfaceAddressFamily": "ipv4",
                    "srEnabled": false,
                    "advertisedHoldTime": 27,
                    "ip4Address": "192.168.0.1",
                    "neighborAddressFamily": "ipv4",
                    "areaIds": [
                      "00.0000"
                    ],
                    "bfdIpv4State": "adminDown",
                    "bfdIpv6State": "adminDown",
                    "grState": ""
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            "0192.0168.0002": {
              "adjacencies": [
                {
                  "state": "up",
                  "circuitId": "00",
                  "routerIdV4": "0.0.0.0",
                  "interfaceName": "Port-Channel2",
                  "lastHelloTime": 1651827050,
                  "level": "level-2",
                  "snpa": "P2P",
                  "hostname": "london",
                  "details": {
                    "stateChanged": 1651599433,
                    "grSupported": "Supported",
                    "interfaceAddressFamily": "ipv4",
                    "srEnabled": false,
                    "advertisedHoldTime": 30,
                    "ip4Address": "192.168.0.2",
                    "neighborAddressFamily": "ipv4",
                    "areaIds": [
                      "00.0000"
                    ],
                    "bfdIpv4State": "adminDown",
                    "bfdIpv6State": "adminDown",
                    "grState": ""
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `json.loads`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Im using json.load for this kind. But i was stuck in the deeper end here.
I was fishing if there is some additional package that could ease up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code snippet will give you the output you want, but next time you are encouraged to try for yourself first and reach us for help about the code you tried.

```py
import json

d = json.loads('''
{
  "vrfs": {
    "default": {
      "isisInstances": {
        "XXX": {
          "neighbors": {
            "0192.0168.0001": {
              "adjacencies": [
                {
                  "state": "up",
                  "circuitId": "01",
                  "routerIdV4": "0.0.0.0",
                  "interfaceName": "Port-Channel1",
                  "lastHelloTime": 1651827049,
                  "level": "level-2",
                  "snpa": "P2P",
                  "hostname": "paris",
                  "details": {
                    "stateChanged": 1651599426,
                    "grSupported": "Supported",
                    "interfaceAddressFamily": "ipv4",
                    "srEnabled": false,
                    "advertisedHoldTime": 27,
                    "ip4Address": "192.168.0.1",
                    "neighborAddressFamily": "ipv4",
                    "areaIds": [
                      "00.0000"
                    ],
                    "bfdIpv4State": "adminDown",
                    "bfdIpv6State": "adminDown",
                    "grState": ""
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            "0192.0168.0002": {
              "adjacencies": [
                {
                  "state": "up",
                  "circuitId": "00",
                  "routerIdV4": "0.0.0.0",
                  "interfaceName": "Port-Channel2",
                  "lastHelloTime": 1651827050,
                  "level": "level-2",
                  "snpa": "P2P",
                  "hostname": "london",
                  "details": {
                    "stateChanged": 1651599433,
                    "grSupported": "Supported",
                    "interfaceAddressFamily": "ipv4",
                    "srEnabled": false,
                    "advertisedHoldTime": 30,
                    "ip4Address": "192.168.0.2",
                    "neighborAddressFamily": "ipv4",
                    "areaIds": [
                      "00.0000"
                    ],
                    "bfdIpv4State": "adminDown",
                    "bfdIpv6State": "adminDown",
                    "grState": ""
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
''')

neighbors = d['vrfs']['default']['isisInstances']['XXX']['neighbors']

for neighbor in neighbors:
    adjacencies = neighbors[neighbor]['adjacencies']
    for adjacency in adjacencies:
        print(f"{neighbor},{adjacency['state']},{adjacency['hostname']},{adjacency['details']['ip4Address']}")
```

The above code will result in:

```
0192.0168.0001,up,paris,192.168.0.1
0192.0168.0002,up,london,192.168.0.2
```

Comment: Big thanks i was stuck on neighbor id couldn't figure out the syntax.

Comment: No worries. I'm glad it worked.